# Web Api 2 empty string parameter GET

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

i have setup the route to be:
[Route("{id}/users/search/{search}")]
and the associated action is:
SomeAction(int id, string text)

The service has the following function.
for the resource with id={id} and the users of this resource get the users that match with the {search} term (username, email etc).

the {search} can have a value so the service returns only the matching entities or does not have a value (empty string or null) so the service returns everything.

For the part with a value it works fine.
For the second part i cannot find something to set the get request that matches the empty string.

i tried the following:
1/users/search/null {search} = "null"
1/users/search/ does not match route
1/users/search does not match route

has anyone a hint how this could be done?

Update: i have tried to replace the action:
SomeAction(int id, string text)
with:
SomeAction(Model model) where model is

```
public class ApplicationUserSearchModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string MatchText { get; set; }
}
```

with no luck since i don't know what to send in order to match the url to this.

Answer (score 8):

You should tag your `search` parameter with `?` to mark it as optional in the route, and set it to `null` by default in your action.

```
[Route("{id}/users/search/{search?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search(int id, string search = null)
```

---

**I originally thought the route/action parameter names were the issue, but I was incorrect. Here is the previous answer:**

The parameter names in your route definition and your action don't match, which is causing your problem.

```
[Route("{id}/users/search/{search}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search(int id, string text)
```

You should update the `string` parameter in your action from `text` to `search`, to match the parameter name in your `Route` attribute.

Comment: the problem is not the service itself. that works fine. given the above route how do you call this service with the {search} binding to a empty string is the question!

Comment: i will try it but i think i have already with no luck.
Still i don't know how to call the service in order to get this result. Any insight how you do it, since yours seem to work?

Comment: You should be able to access this route by calling 

GET http://website/1234/users/search
or
GET http://website/1234/users/search/firstname%20lastname